# Are there anybody implemented a framebuffer with BitmapData in flash to replace its display list?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, bitmapdata

If anyone has a framebuffer implementation, could you please share some performance benchmarks? Or at least tell me how much difference are there in your point of view.

I need to make a flash game which has almost 1K 50x50 bitmaps moving on screen(more than 10K display object in display list), and want to know if flash can support it well on a normal PC with at least 30FPS.

Comment: I would advise you to first try to abstract the native display list into a framebuffer class that works using Bitmap class objects as part of the display list and measure its performance, and only then compare it to an eventual framebuffer bitmap class you or someone else would write. If you haven't already, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at the [flixel library](http://flixel.org/) for a rasterize library and for a bitmap versus display list comparison have a look at this [blog post](http://blog.iainlobb.com/2010/11/display-list-vs-blitting-results.html)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this pretty easily if you use BitmapData and you don't need to rotate your sprites. Here is an example of 10,000 3x3 pixel sprites - I have used this same technique on 7,000 50x50 pixel spites and it runs just fine:

http://actionsnippet.com/?p=224